# Toggle between two values

Tags: javascript, arraylist, highcharts, togglebutton

I'm trying to switch **data** value to **animal** or **plant** base on my selection and I want to maintain **animal** array as *default*. my code ain't working and is there a way to safely do this without crashing too much into global space

```js
let animal = ['cat','dog','lion'];
let plant =['Orange','Mango','banana'];
//-----//defult----
data = animal; 
let toolTipsMsg ='Animal distribution';
//-----//defult----



let anima = document.querySelector('#animalBtn');
let plan = document.querySelector('#plantBtn');

function fnAnimal(){
  if(data !== animal){
    window.data =  animal;
    window.toolTipMsg ='Animal distribution';
  }
}

function fnPlant(){
  if(data !== plant){
    window.data = plant;
    window.toolTipMsg ='Plant distribution';
  }
}

anima.addEventListener('click', fnAnimal, false);
plan.addEventListener('click', fnPlant, false);

document.getElementById('show').innerHTML = data.toString();
```

```html
 <!--//button-->
 <div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle">
        <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" >
            <input type="radio" name="source" id="animalBtn" autocomplete="off"> Animal
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-outline-primary">
            <input type="radio" name="source" id="plantBtn" autocomplete="off" > Plant
        </label>
    </div>
    <p id='show'> </p>
<!--//button-->
```

Answer (score 1):

Without making too many changes, the below code works to change the value in `#show` by adding the `document.getElementById('show').innerHTML = data.toString();` inside each event handler.

```js
let animal = ['cat','dog','lion'];
let plant =['Orange','Mango','banana'];
//-----//defult----
data = animal; 
let toolTipsMsg ='Animal distribution';
//-----//defult----

let anima = document.querySelector('#animalBtn');
let plan = document.querySelector('#plantBtn');

function fnAnimal(){
  if(data !== animal){
    window.data =  animal;
    window.toolTipMsg ='Animal distribution';
  }
  document.getElementById('show').innerHTML = data.toString();
}

function fnPlant(){
  if(data !== plant){
    window.data = plant;
    window.toolTipMsg ='Plant distribution';
  }
  document.getElementById('show').innerHTML = data.toString();
}

anima.addEventListener('click', fnAnimal, false);
plan.addEventListener('click', fnPlant, false);
```

```html
 <!--//button-->
 <div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle">
        <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" >
            <input type="radio" name="source" id="animalBtn" autocomplete="off"> Animal
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-outline-primary">
            <input type="radio" name="source" id="plantBtn" autocomplete="off" > Plant
        </label>
    </div>
    <p id='show'> </p>
<!--//button-->
```

If you want to keep your variables from leaking into the global scope, you can wrap your code in a self-executing function, e.g.

```
(function() {
  // your code here
})();
```

You should then remove the `window` prefix for your variables.

Answer (score 1):

Put your data in an object that uses the source as the keys. Then you can easily add more sources without having to write new code for each of them.

You need to update the inner HTML in the click handler.

```js
let sources = {
  animal: { list: ['cat','dog','lion'], tooltip: 'Animal distribution'},
  plant: { list: ['Orange','Mango','banana'], tooltip: 'Plant distribution'}
};

let anima = document.querySelector('#animalBtn');
let plan = document.querySelector('#plantBtn');

function selectSource(source) {
  sources.current = sources[source];
  window.toolTipMsg = sources.current.tooltip;
  document.getElementById('show').innerHTML = sources.current.list.toString();
  
}

anima.addEventListener('click', function(e) {selectSource(e.currentTarget.dataset.source);}, false);
plan.addEventListener('click', function(e) {selectSource(e.currentTarget.dataset.source);}, false);

selectSource("animal");
```

```html
<!--//button-->
 <div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle">
        <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" >
            <input type="radio" name="source" id="animalBtn" data-source = "animal"> Animal
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-outline-primary">
            <input type="radio" name="source" id="plantBtn" data-source="plant"> Plant
        </label>
    </div>
    <p id='show'> </p>
<!--//button-->
```